# Combining 2 tresholded images to get this effect

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following 2 images:
[image]

How could I combine the images to get any of these 2 images?
[image]

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('skadi.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('greyscale',gray)
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('treshold',binary)
binary= 255 - binary
cv2.imshow('inverted',binary)
kernel = np.ones((25, 25), np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(binary, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow('closing',closing)
#closing = 255-closing
closing2 =  cv2.bitwise_not(closing)
cv2.imshow('invetedclosing',closing2)
result = cv2.bitwise_or(closing, closing2)
cv2.imshow('convned',result)
edges = cv2.Canny(result, 100, 200)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried combining them wit `cv2.bitwise_or` and `cv2.bitwise_xor`, but ended with a white screen.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Add the two images at the top to get the one at the bottom left. Then invert that to get the one at the bottom right

Comment: @fmw42 Wouldn't the addition of those images produce an all white image instead?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I was just looking at the main figures. One would need to get the contours and draw again combined on the opposite background.

Comment: @fmw42 No problem! Maybe if you flood-fill the top left image at the background with black, leaving only the "holes" in white and then you add it to the right top image the idea could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a handy script that basically extracts the biggest white blob in a binary image. Since the biggest white blob in your image is blob is the foreground (and the shape you are looking for), this should give you the expected result.

It basically gets all the external contours and keeps the contour with the biggest area. It then draws it on a new image.

This is the code, I'm using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dksc4.png) image, since you did not provide the original.

```
# Imports:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + "testBlob.png")

# Grayscale conversion:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold via Otsu:
# Note the image inversion:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Store a copy of the input image:
biggestBlob = binaryImage.copy()
# Set initial values for the
# largest contour:
largestArea = 0
largestContourIndex = 0

# Find the contours on the binary image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binaryImage, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Get the largest contour in the contours list:
for i, cc in enumerate(contours):
    # Find the area of the contour:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cc)
    # Store the index of the largest contour:
    if area > largestArea:
        largestArea = area
        largestContourIndex = i

# Once we get the biggest blob, paint it black:
tempMat = binaryImage.copy()
cv2.drawContours(tempMat, contours, largestContourIndex, (0, 0, 0), -1, 8, hierarchy)

# Erase smaller blobs:
biggestBlob = biggestBlob - tempMat

# Show the result:
cv2.imshow("biggestBlob", biggestBlob)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the result:

[image]